# NLP text preprocessing

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I am doing a small project on amazon product reviews. During text pre-processing self is unable to process the following things from the text.

**Problem 1:** user has written a review like this

> The laptop is over all very good.: But few  points to note:
>
> 1. The sound is not that much good
> 2. camera is ok

After processing this text using `re.sub` expression & lemmatization still the point numbers are present in the output along with colon.

```
text = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', X['long_review'][i]) 
text = re.sub(r'\[[0-9]*\]', ' ', X['long_review'][i])  
text = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', X['long_review'][i]) 
text = re.sub(r'\d', ' ', X['long_review'][i]) 
## below code to remove the emoji in the sentences
text = re.sub('[(\U0001F600-\U0001F92F|\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF|\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF|\U0001F190-\U0001F1FF|\U00002702-\U000027B0|\U0001F926-\U0001FA9F|\u200d|\u2640-\u2642|\u2600-\u2B55|\u23cf|\u23e9|\u231a|\ufe0f)]+', '' , X['long_review'][i])
```

The output looks like this:

> laptop good.: point note: 1. sound much good.

**Problem 2:** input user review

> Core i7 10th gen in 60k! Are you kidding me!

The output:

> core i7 10th gen 60k! kidding me!

Required help to process these kinds of texts

Comment: You overwrite text with the last replacement as you pass `X['long_review'][i]` again. You could pass the modified version of `text` instead. Note that `[^a-zA-Z]` matches any char except a-zA-Z so it will also match a digit, whitespace char and the emoji's.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass updated text to the next sub() function to get updated along with the previous update.

Currently, you are passing fresh value every time to sub(), `'[^a-zA-Z]'` removes dot or digit from the string and then pass updated to the next processing function.

```
text = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', X['long_review'][i]) 
text = re.sub(r'\[[0-9]*\]', ' ', text)  
text = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', text) 
text = re.sub(r'\d', ' ', text)
 
## below code to remove the emoji in the sentences
text = re.sub('[(\U0001F600-\U0001F92F|\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF|\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF|\U0001F190-\U0001F1FF|\U00002702-\U000027B0|\U0001F926-\U0001FA9F|\u200d|\u2640-\u2642|\u2600-\u2B55|\u23cf|\u23e9|\u231a|\ufe0f)]+', '' , text)
```